# VS 2012 Lightswitch and MySQL

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2012, form-authentication, lightswitch-2012

I'm currently experiencing a problem which I'm not 100% certain about the part which is making the trouble, so I'm just gonna tell you guys what I'm trying to do and actually doing.

Its about trying and more or less failing by deploying a Lightswitch desktop application (local) with form authentication using MySQL

1. Create a new Lightswith app in VS 2012 with integrated Lightswitch
2. Selecting the DB Source with the connection wizard to my root servers MySQL
3. Importing the tables etc.
4. Creating some screens
5. Trying to deploy everything, works fine until it comes to providing the database connection for probably creating the authentication data - cause there's simply no MySQL Connector to select
   .. that's where I stuck.

It seems like when I remove the form authentication everything's working fine.
Any Ideas?
Is the form authentication in Lightswitch with the use of MySQL simple not supported or is that a problem with the .NET Connector itself?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Forms Authentication with MySQL is not supported. You can certainly use MySQL tables/views in your Lightswitch application, but I'm under the impression that Lightswitch needs to use a SQL Server database (be it a local MDF file or one a standalone server) to use Forms Authentication.

Comment: Yeah, seems like that ... a big shame that MySQL is still not 100% supported.
The bad thing is, I couldn't even write my own rolebased authentication - there was just no way how to save the current logged user session .. Lightswitch is just horrible without the mssql server >,<